# Test if an argument of a function is set or not in R

Tags: r, function, variables, variable-assignment, isset

I have a function `f` that takes two parameters (`p1` and `p2`):

If for the parameter `p2` no value was passed to the function, the value of `p1`^2 should be used instead. But how can I find out within the function, if a value is given or not. The problem is that the variable `p2` is not initialized if there was no value. Thus I can't test for `p2` being `NULL`.

```
f <- function(p1, p2) {
    if(is.null(p2)) {
        p2=p1^2
    }
    p1-p2
}
```

Is it somehow possible to check if a value for `p2` was passed to the function or not? (I could not find an `isset()` - function or similar things.)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You use the function `missing()` for that.

```
f <- function(p1, p2) {
    if(missing(p2)) {
        p2=p1^2
    }
    p1-p2
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the value of p2 to NULL by default. I sometimes prefer that solution, as it allows for passing arguments to nested functions.

```
f <- function(p1, p2=NULL) {
    if(is.null(p2)) {
        p2=p1^2
    }
    p1-p2
}

f.wrapper <-function(p1,p2=NULL){
    p1 <- 2*p1
    f(p1,p2)
}
> f.wrapper(1)
[1] -2
> f.wrapper(1,3)
[1] -1
```

EDIT: you could do this technically with `missing()` as well, but then you would have to include a `missing()` statement in `f.wrapper` as well.

Comment: +1 for the `NULL` default alternative. Re: the EDIT you added, how would you pass `missing`'ness down through the wrapper function?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Passing `missing`-ness on is complicated AFAIK - but possible. That's why `NULL` is so much easier in this case.

Comment: ... So a separate  question might be warranted for passing `missing`-ness on.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien That would have to be `if(missing(p2)) f(p1) else f(p1,p2)`. Or you could pass the arguments using the dots argument.

Comment: Thanks.  FWIW, I can't see how to do this with dots, if both functions have formal args `p1` and `p2`.  Another alternative uses the following in the body of `f.wrapper()`: `{cl <- match.call(); cl$p1 <- 2*p1; cl[[1]] <- f; eval(cl)}`. All this goes to show just how much cleaner your `NULL` alternative really is!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien : you only give `f` the formal args `p1` and `p2`. `f.wrapper <- function(p1, ...){ blabla f(p1, ...)}`. That would work and is how it's often done in R itself

Answer (score 8):

I think '?missing' should do it.

Answer (score 8):

In a case like this you can also use something like this:

```
f <- function(p1, p2 = p1 ^ 2) {
    p1-p2
}
```

See the part on Lazy evaluation at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

Comment: I usually write it like this, so when would `missing` be most appropriate?

Comment: @Diego, if you look at the ?missing documentation you'll find an example that would be difficult to implement using this technique.