# How to write a wrapper function which can honour default values, when the target function has ones?

Tags: r

I'd like to write a more-or-less generic caller to `targetf` that retains its default parameters.

Suppose we have a provided by some 3rd party library `targetf`:

```
targetf<-function(x=1,...){
    print(paste("x =",x))
}
```

How to write `wrapperf`, that will respect `targetf`s default arguments, so calling
`wrapperf()` would not yield the error message `Error in paste("x =", x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default`?

The obvious candidate `wrapperf1<-function(x,y) {targetf(x=x)}` doesn't work and fails with `wrapperf1()`.

The `wrapperf2<-function(...) {targetf(...)}` behaves correctly, but it doesn't work for me, because I only care to pass the `x` argument, (and possibly reserve the `...` to other functions in `wrapperf` body).

Maybe to solve the issue I'd have to play with ellipsis filtering, which is a *terra incognita* for me at the moment...

---

One idea on how to solve the problem: maybe I'd need to create a specially crafted `...` object from scratch in `wrapperf` to do pseudo code like this:

```
wrapperfX<-function(x,y,...)
{
    ...<-if(missing(x){
            list()
        }else{
            list(x=x)
        }
    targetf(...)
}
```

But I have no idea how to even start doing assignments into ellipsis... are the possible at all? I put this question separately on SO: [Is it possible to create an ellipsis (`…`) object from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671118/is-it-possible-to-create-an-ellipsis-object-from-scratch)

---

Since the problem is still unsolved I decided to post this question to r-help@r-project.org

Comment: You could use "list(...)" and check in result if you find your argument. Anyhow, there is a problem if you declare wrapperf1 with two arguments (without default values), and call it with none. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function).

Comment: +1. Interesting question. This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964830/test-if-an-argument-of-a-function-is-set-or-not-in-r

Comment: @Frank Of course I can manually cook calls to `targetf` with all possible combinations of missing parameters (which number will explore like n!) but it wouldn't be much general.

Comment: But it gave me idea: since R is interpreted, I can create such wrapper function dynamically... that would be a little cheating, but in principle it should work. And the generating function will definitely not be one-liner...

Comment: Why not put the same default parameters in the argument list of your wrapper function?

Comment: @Carl Because I never know, which parameters have default values. Passing missing parameters for which the default exists, will override the default with missing, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Then you're pretty much limited to using `list(...)` internally.  But unless you're trying to write a wrapper which passes the "wrapped" function as one of its parameters, you do in fact always know what the defaults are for the function you're calling, so I still don't see the problem.

Comment: @Carl Then how? `formals(targetf)` doesn't help here, if the `targetf` calls another function with default parameters, using `nestedtargetf(...)`; e.g. the `fitdist` function from `fitdistplus` library calls internaly `mmedist(...)`.

Comment: @SimonO101 Of course. I didn't know they exist. I could swear, that've I never seen a flag, that someone did asnwer them.

Comment: I've also got a reply from Gerrit Eichner from r-help@r-project.org list, that suggests to use `match.call` with `expand.dots=FALSE`. It's interesting thought, and I'll try to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll reply myself with even more elaborate setup (I replaced `targetf` with `lib*` names). The `bar` functions are nested inside `foo` ones, so their default values are not easily visible to the user.

```
libfoo<-function(par1=1,...)
{
    if (missing(par1))
    {
        warning("par1 is missing!!")
    }
    print(paste0('par1: ',par1))
    libbar(...)
}


libbar<-function(par2=1)
{
    if (missing(par2))
    {
        warning("par2 is missing!!")
    }
    print(paste0('par2: ',par2))
}


libfoo2<-function(par3=1,...)
{
    if (missing(par3))
    {
        warning("par3 is missing!!")
    }
    print(paste0('par3: ',par3))
    libbar2(...)
}

libbar2<-function(par4=1)
{
    if (missing(par4))
    {
        warning("par4 is missing!!")
    }
    print(paste0('par4: ',par4))
}
```

The wrapper:

```
wrapfun<-function(x,par1=3,...,par3,par4)
{
    libfoo(par1,...) #With dots everything is simple

    pars<-list()
    if(!missing(par3))
    {
        pars<-c(pars,par3=par3)
    }
    if(!missing(par4))
    {
        pars<-c(pars,par4=par4)
    }
    do.call(libfoo2,pars) #This is how we can pass specific arguments, and respecting missings properly.
}
```

This is some output:

```
wrapfun(par1=5,par2=5,par3=5,par4=5)
# [1] "par1: 5"
# [1] "par2: 5"
# [1] "par3: 5"
# [1] "par4: 5"


wrapfun()
# [1] "par1: 3"
# [1] "par2: 1"
# [1] "par3: 1"
# [1] "par4: 1"
# Warning messages:
# 1: In libbar(...) : par2 is missing!!
# 2: In (function (par3 = 1, ...)  : par3 is missing!!
# 3: In libbar2(...) : par4 is missing!!

wrapfun(par4=5)
# [1] "par1: 3"
# [1] "par2: 1"
# [1] "par3: 1"
# [1] "par4: 5"
# Warning messages:
# 1: In libbar(...) : par2 is missing!!
# 2: In (function (par3 = 1, ...)  : par3 is missing!!
```