# Is it possible to create an ellipsis (`...`) object from scratch?

Tags: r

I found the solution for passing missing arguments to functions with defaults using such a pseudo code:

```
wrapperfX<-function(x)
{
    ...<-if(missing(x){
            list()
        }else{
            list(x=x)
        }
    targetf(...)
}
```

How much are these things allowed in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick you are looking for is perhaps to use `do.call` which lets you call a function and specify the arguments as a list:

```
wrapperfX <- function(x){
  dots<-if(missing(x)){
    list()
  }else{
    list(x=x)
  }
  do.call(targetf,dots)
}
```

This lets you specify named arguments as well if the list elements have names.

```
> do.call(log,list(x=10,base=10))
[1] 1
```

is equivalent to

```
log(x=10,base=10)
```

If the function you are calling is expressed in terms of dot-dot-dots, then the arguments will me matched in the same way as if you'd put them in the function call.

[also you had a missing parenthesis in, appropriately, `missing((x){` :) ]

Comment: It works perfectly. Since wrapper functions should be very fast  I wonder, how much this hackery is inefficient; function calls are relatively expensive in R + list construction is not for free as well...

Answer (score 2):

If your function depends on the *unevaluated* expression, you may want to use `substitute`, to avoid evaluation of the `...` calls inside the wrapper.

Example:

```
f <- function(...) deparse(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L])

wrap <- function(x){
    L <- if(missing(x)) list() else list(x)
    do.call(f, L)
}

wrap2 <- function(x){
    L <- if(missing(x)) list() else list(substitute(x))
    do.call(f, L)
}
```

Note how `wrap2` doesn't "touch" the arguments:

```
f(1+2+3)      # "list(1 + 2 + 3)"
wrap(1+2+3)   # "list(6)"
wrap2(1+2+3)  # "list(1 + 2 + 3)"
```

For empty calls, they are indistinguishable:

```
f()      # "list()"
wrap()   # "list()"
wrap2()  # "list()"
```