# Defining default R function parameters on processed arguments

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a package function that needs defaults parameters to work, but whose values have to be taken from processed (other) arguments of the function.
As of now, I'm doing it like so :

```
myfunc <- function(x, y, n=NULL){
  processed <- some_other_func(x,y)
  x <- processed$x
  y <- processed$y
  if(is.null(n)){
    n <- length(intersect(x,y))/3
  }
  # do stuff
}
```

But ideally, I'd like a default expression to be put instead of `NULL` because it seems inconsistent if my doc says that the default is `length(intersect(x,y))/3`.

Do you know of a way I could specify the default parameter to be more comprehensible ?

Comment: Maybe `missing()` instead of `is.null()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964830/test-if-an-argument-of-a-function-is-set-or-not-in-r

Comment: if this default requires the input of other function arguments, I don't really see any better way than what you are doing.

Comment: Note that `n=NULL`, imo, is a legit default value, just specify in the docs that it'll be set to `length(..)` if missing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could solve it something like this?

```
default_function <- function(v1, v2)
{
  return((v1 + v2)/2)
}

dummy_function <- function(x, y, n = default_function)
{
  x = x
  y = y
  if(class(n) == "function") n = n(x,y) # if n is any kind of function do it

  print(paste(x, y, n))

}


dummy_function(1, 2)
dummy_function(1, 2, 100)
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure it would be doable since `default_function` would need the *processed* `x` and `y`.

Comment: Im not sure if i understand you right, but the default function, stored in n, should be able to recieve the processed x and y values when it is executed in the if-case?

Comment: But to be honest, i think setting n = NULL and giving an explanation in the docs as @RLave suggested is easier to understand than the suggested method with n = some sort of function here.

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. People will just have to start reading the doc :P