# How do I return a data-variable in an R function?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, evaluation, tidyeval

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to write a function that returns the names of certain variables of a dataset. For a test tibble `test <- tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2=2:4, x3=3:5, x4=4:6)`, I want a function

```
assign_predictors_argument <- function(dataset, outcome, predictors) {
  ...
}
```

such that:

1. if the argument `predictors` is not defined, `predictors` will be set to all variables in `dataset` apart from `outcome`. E.g. `assign_predictors_argument(test, x1)` will return `c(x2, x3, x4)`.
2. if the argument `predictors` is defined, will return that value. E.g. `assign_predictors_argument(test, x1, c(x2, x3))` will return `c(x2, x3)`.

---

**What I have tried**

```
assign_predictors_argument <- function(dataset, outcome, predictors) {
  if(missing(predictors)) {
    predictors <- dataset %>%
      dplyr::select( -{{ outcome }} ) %>%
      names()
  }
  predictors
}
```

---

**What went wrong**

**Case 1: predictors argument missing**

`assign_predictors_argument(test, x1)` gives the result `"x2" "x3" "x4"`. However, I want this to return `c(x2,x3, x4)`.

How do I convert this character vector to a form like the input?

**Case 2: predictors argument defined**

`assign_predictors_argument(test, x1, c(x2, x3))` gives

```
Error in assign_predictors_argument(test, x1, x2) : 
  object 'x2' not found
```

It appears that the last line of the function tries to evaluate and return `predictors`. As x3 is not defined in the environment, this brings an error.

I have tried a) changing the final line to `{{predictors}}` as well as b) changing `missing(predictors)` to `is.null(predictors)` and putting in a default `predictors = NULL` (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964830/test-if-an-argument-of-a-function-is-set-or-not-in-r)). Neither have worked.

How can I return the value of `predictors` without either a) changing its form or b) evaluating it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "I want this to return c(x2,x3, x4)"? Do you mean a data frame containing these variables? Do you mean a defused R expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close:

```
assign_predictors_argument <- function(dataset, outcome, predictors) {
  if(missing(predictors)) {
    dataset %>%
      dplyr::select( -{{ outcome }} ) %>%
      names() %>%
      {rlang::expr( c(!!!syms(.)) )}
  }
  else rlang::enexpr(predictors)
}

assign_predictors_argument(test, x1)
# c(x2, x3, x4)
assign_predictors_argument(test, x1, c(x2, x3))
# c(x2, x3)
```

In the above, `rlang::expr()` constructs the expression that you want by 1) converting names to symbols with `syms()` and 2) splicing them together inside the `c(...)` expression with the unquote-splice operator `!!!`.

For the second portion, you can simply capture the expression supplied by the user with `rlang::enexpr()`.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to return something like `c(x2, x3, x4)`. Let's first be clear what this object is. It is an unevaluated `call` to the function `c`. It is *not* a vector of names. You will be able to use it in tidy evaluation, but it will require the `!!` operator.

This is quite tricky to achieve. You need to capture the `predictors` argument and ensure it is either a single variable name or a call to `c`. Any other expression passed to `predictors` should probably throw an error.

If `predictors` is missing and you are getting the column names as characters, then you must convert these to names with `as.name` and stick them in a `c` call. If `predictors` is a single variable, it must be returned unevaluated. If it is a `c` call, it should also be returned unevaluated. Otherwise an error is thrown.

So the function might look something like this:

```r
assign_predictors_argument <- function(dataset, outcome, predictors) {
  if(missing(predictors)) {
    predictors <- dataset %>%
      dplyr::select( -{{ outcome }} ) %>%
      names() %>%
      sapply(as.name, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
      predictors <- as.call(c(quote(c), predictors))
  } else {
   predictors <- as.list(match.call())$predictors
   if(is.call(predictors))
   {
     f_name <- as.list(predictors)[[1]]
     if(as.character(substitute(f_name)) != "c")
       stop("'predictors' must be either a single variable or vector of names")
   }
  }
  predictors
}
```

So let's test it out:

```r
test <- dplyr::tibble(x1 = 1:3, x2 = 2:4, x3 = 3:5, x4 = 4:6)

# Test with missing predictors
assign_predictors_argument(test, x1)
#> c(x2, x3, x4)

# Test with single predictor
assign_predictors_argument(test, x1, x2)
#> x2

# Test with multiple predictors
assign_predictors_argument(test, x1, c(x3, x4))
#> c(x3, x4)

# Test with call other than call to c
assign_predictors_argument(test, x1, as.name("x3"))
#> Error in assign_predictors_argument(test, x1, as.name("x3")): 
#>  'predictors' must be either a single variable or vector of names
```

This all looks correct. So to use it, we might do something like this:

```
vars <- assign_predictors_argument(test, x1, c(x2, x4))

vars
#> c(x2, x4)

test %>% select(!!vars)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      x2    x4
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     2     4
#> 2     3     5
#> 3     4     6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>